# Make ParallelEnumerable.OrderBy stable sort

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, parallel-processing, plinq

I'm sorting a list of objects by their integer ids in parallel using `OrderBy`. I have a few objects with the same id and need the sort to be stable.

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.orderby), the parallelized `OrderBy` is not stable, but there is an implementation approach to make it stable. However, I cannot find an example of this.

```
var list = new List<pair>() { new pair("a", 1), new pair("b", 1), new pair("c", 2), new pair("d", 3), new pair("e", 4) };
var newList = list.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(4).OrderBy<pair, int>(p => p.order);

private class pair {
  private String name;
  public int order;
 
  public pair (String name, int order) {
    this.name = name;
    this.order = order;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried ThenBy as well, but haven't gotten it to work.

Comment: Are you saying that the example in the remarks of the the other `OrderBy` method doesn't work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383662.aspx

Comment: I thought I had clicked on both of the method pages but apparently I was looking at the wrong overloaded method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The remarks for [the other `OrderBy` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383662.aspx) suggest this approach:

```
var newList = list
   .Select((pair, index) => new { pair, index })
   .AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
   .OrderBy(p => p.pair.order)
   .ThenBy(p => p.index)
   .Select(p => p.pair);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the clearer code example as well. Microsoft's use of variable names e and i wasn't too clear.