# Sort IQueryable by specific order

Tags: c#, sorting, iqueryable

I have a table that I want to pull items by name in a certain order and by date.

```
id name  date
1  XYZ   1:30
2  ABC   1:40
3  LMNOQ  1:50
4  ABC   1:20
```

I created the order

```
List<string> itemNames = new List<string>();
       documentOrder.Add("XYZ");
       documentOrder.Add("ABC");     
       documentOrder.Add("LMNOQ");
```

Then pulled the data, I think order will stay intact.

```
var myTable = _context.TheTable.Where(x => itemNames.Contains(x.id));
```

myTable data will look like

```
id name  date
1  XYZ   1:30
2  ABC   1:40
4  ABC   1:20
3  LMNOQ  1:50
```

Now I need to sort by dates without messing up the name order. I need it look like this.

```
id name  date
1  XYZ   1:30
2  ABC   1:20
4  ABC   1:40
3  LMNOQ  1:50
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# List<> Sort by x then y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289010/c-sharp-list-sort-by-x-then-y)

Comment: Is what you try to achieve [a stable sort on Date column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13710006/7034621)?

Answer (score 3):

```
var myTable = _context.TheTable.Where(x => itemNames.Contains(x.id))
                      .OrderBy(x => x.name).ThenBy(x => x.date);
```

Answer (score 2):

When using an `IQueryable` you can get it ordered as you want (by name, then by date... which looks a bit like a time) with multiple ordering statements.

```
var orderedQueryable = queryable.OrderBy(q => q.Name).ThenBy(q => q.Date);
```

Comment: If I OrderBy Name, won't that order the name Alphabetically?

Comment: @user1854438 yes it will. Your question shows them alphabetically... did you want something different?

Comment: Yeah, sorry my example was a mistake. I'll update the question

Comment: To simply "preserve the original name order", you'll need to populate an additional property, so you can still order. For example, if you iterate the collection and assign an order integer to each row, and increment it each time the name changes, you could order by "OriginalOrder" then by "Date".